# i can not with pip install lxml

Tags: python-3.x, pip, lxml

When I want to install lxml, I encounter this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lxml
```

Even when I try to update pip, I get an error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pip/
```

Comment: what system are you on? Are you using Mac?

Comment: This is a network issue. Do you need to set a proxy to connect to the www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `pip install lxml==3.4.2`